# Glassfish 3.1 - Cannot find javadb client

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-3, derby

In eclipise, how to get rid that warning message when launching a se application like that

```
....
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
p.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost:3700");
Context context = new InitialContext(p);
....
```

:

```
04-avr.-2012 11:23:39 com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.CommonClassLoaderServiceImpl findDerbyClient
INFO: Cannot find javadb client jar file, derby jdbc driver will not be available by default.
```

Answer (score 1):

The "javadb client jar file" is named "derbyclient.jar", and you should find it as part of the javadb installation, or you can get it from http://db.apache.org/derby